Proof of $\frac{3}{5}(2^{\frac{1}{3}}-1) ≤ \Omega ≤ 1$
Prove that $$\frac{3}{5}(2^{\frac{1}{3}}-1) ≤ \Omega ≤ 1$$
where $$\Omega = \int_0^1 \frac{x^4}{(1+x^6)^\frac{2}{3}} \,dx. $$
I have been trying this problem from quite some time now and I'm quite confused as to how we approach such kind, where I suppose we use $f(x) = \frac{x^4}{(1+x^6)^{2/3}}$ ($x ≠ 0$). $f(x)$ is an increasing function  with $f(0) = 0$  and $f(1)=\frac{1}{2^{2/3}}$. Since it is a new kind of problem to new, I would really appreciate simpler approach/idea.

Hint for the upper bound: $$
\frac{{x^4 }}{{(1 + x^6 )^{2/3} }} \le \frac{{x^4 }}{{(x^6 )^{2/3} }} = \frac{{x^4 }}{{x^4 }} = 1
$$ for $0<x<1$.

Does this answer your question? Need to prove $\frac{3}{5}(2^{\frac{1}{3}}-1)\le\int_0^1\frac{x^4}{(1+x^6)^{\frac{2}{3}}}dx\le1$ - found using an Approach0 search.
